# Python class cannot be instantiated through Terminal

Tags: python, class

For educational purposes, I want to show how classes work in Python.

My demonstration is to go to the terminal, use Vim to create a new file `classy.py` and then run Python on the terminal.

I begin typing `vi classy.py`, entering insert mode with `i`, and then I type:

```
# An example of a class
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

and save. I then enter Python2.7 through the Terminal. I type `python` and then at the prompt

```
>>> import classy             # import classy.py
>>> rectangle = Shape(10,10)  # create instance of the Shape class
```

Terminal outputs an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Shape' is not defined
```

Why does this error occur? Surely there should be no problem instantiating the class `rectangle = Shape(10,10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrongly , either you need to give `module.ClassName` to access the Class or import it using `from <module> import <Class>`

Examples -

```
>>> import classy       
>>> rectangle = classy.Shape(10,10)
```

Or

```
>>> from classy import Shape     
>>> rectangle = Shape(10,10)
```

Comment: Also, note you can use `from <module> import *`, which will import all definitions - after that, you can use them without module prefix.
El psy congroo.

Answer (score 0):

```
rectangle = classy.Shape(10,10)
```